# Can a factory contain only one color or is there a rule to redraw four tiles?

Tags: house-rules, azul

When I play the physical version of Azul, I redraw tiles if all four that I place in a single factory are the same color. Recently [Board Game Arena added Azul](https://boardgamearena.com/gamepanel?game=azul) and I started a game. One of the rounds started with four blues in a factory:

[image: Four blues in a single factory.]

I started writing up a bug report, but [looking at the rules](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/153088/azul-english-rules) I don't actually see anything that disallows that. Am I playing with a house rule? Is there any reason to not allow this situation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing in the rules that requires a re-draw of factory tiles - it can happen, and when it does then there will be a player who gets all four of those tiles without leaving anything on the table. It's probably advantageous for whoever gets to choose it most of the time, but it won't always be desirable - e.g. if that player has already committed to a different colour on their bottom rows.

Redrawing would be a house rule, and I don't think there's anything stopping you from playing that way, but you might need to work out what happens in the (exceedingly rare) situation when there isn't enough tiles for a redraw, or all the remaining tiles are the same colour.

Comment: It's already a rare situation and I can't think of how the house rule improves the game. So I think I'll just drop it. ;-)

Comment: The singleton factory is probably also going to be advantageous to whoever takes it. That's just how it works. Getting lucky with a factory is especially helpful is just part of the game.